# how to bind onclick method with keydown method

Tags: javascript

I have an onclick method like this:

```
onClick: function() {
    xx.setValue('i want this to be a button but triggered on keyup');
}
```

And a keyup method like this:

```
var that=this;
this.something().on( 'keyup', function() { 
    xx.setValue('hello'+that.something().getvalue());
} );
```

this is a preview mode. So i want the text from the onclick button to behave like the text i write with the keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the sort of thing you are wanting to achieve here?

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#output').val('You wanted to type:\n' + $('#textBox').val());
});

$('#textBox').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#output').val($('#textBox').val());
});
```

Check out my fiddle to get a better idea of what I'm suggesting http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/jssL1xwq/

If this isn't what you wanted then please can you provide your own fiddle of your code failing to do what you want it to do so we can get some more context on what you are asking.

Cheers
Zac

**[Edit]**

I don't know why I didn't notice you were using native JS for your solution earlier. If you wanted to stick with your native JS and not have to use jQuery here is a solution that does the same as what I did above but in native JS.

```
function changeTextArea(newValue) {
    document.getElementById('output').value = newValue;
 }

function printToTextArea() {
    changeTextArea('You wanted to type:\n' + document.getElementById('textBox').value);
}
```

And I guess the HTML is relevant for this native JS solution too so here it is

```
<input id="textBox" type="text" value="Type Here" onkeyup="changeTextArea(this.value)" />
<br />
<input id="button" type="button" value="Tell me what I typed" onclick="printToTextArea()"/>
<br />
<textArea id="output"></textArea>
```

And here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/jssL1xwq/1/

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't this work ?

Html:

```
<input type=button id=btn value='Submit' onclick=otherFunction(); />
<input type=button id=button value='Submit' onclick=myFunction(); />
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

and this:

```
function myFunction(){
      $(#btn).click();
}

function otherFunction(){
      alert('this');
}
```

Note that with jquery you have the keup event :

https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

in this case you could have :

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $(#btn).click();
});
```